# show glyphicon based on value html angular

Tags: html, angularjs

controller:

```
.controller('BlogController', function(blogFactory, $routeParams, $scope){

    var that=this;

    stat=false;

    this.checkbookmark = function(bId){
    console.log(bId)
    blogFactory.checkBookmark(bId, function(response){
        console.log(response)
        if(response == "bookmarked"){
            that.stat = true;  
        }
        else{
            that.stat = false;  
        }
    })
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController as blogCtrl">

    <div class="row" ng-repeat="chunk in blogCtrl.blogs | filter: filter_name  | orderBy:'-created_at'  | groupBy: 3">


        <div class="outerbox1 col-sm-4" ng-repeat="blog in chunk" >
            <div class="innerbox3"  ng-init="blogCtrl.checkbookmark(blog._id)">
                <br>
                <div> > READ MORE 
                    <a ng-if="blogCtrl.stat" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.removebookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart pull-right">{{blogCtrl.stat}}</a>
                    <a ng-if="!blogCtrl.stat" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.addbookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty pull-right">{{blogCtrl.stat}}</a> 
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to show glyphicon based on the value of **stat**

I have 6 blogs, first 3 are bookmarked and next 3 are not.

The problem i'm getting is that the **stat** value is always set according to the last bookmark and hence it is always false / true (based on the condition of last blog).

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the stat property on the controller you should set the property on the blog object (it obviously belongs to the object)

Replace your checkbookmark function with this:

```
this.checkbookmark = function(blog){ //pass the entire blog, not just the id
    blogFactory.checkBookmark(blog._id, function(response){
        console.log(response)
        if(response == "bookmarked"){
            blog.stat = true;  //set the property on blog instead of the controller
        }
        else{
            blog.stat = false;  
        }
    })
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<div class="innerbox3"  ng-init="blogCtrl.checkbookmark(blog)">
    <br>
    <div> > READ MORE 
        <a ng-if="blog.stat" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.removebookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart pull-right">{{blog.stat}}</a>
        <a ng-if="!blog.stat" ng-href="#" ng-click="blogCtrl.addbookmark(blog._id)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty pull-right">{{blog.stat}}</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

You will need to make similar changed to your `add` and `removebookmark` functions

Comment: it worked. thanks... now could you please tell me how to update the display in real time, i.e., glyphicon icon to change if a user clicks on it. @x4rf41

Comment: as i said, you need to do the same changes to the add and remove functions: pass the entire blog not just the id and then set the blog.stat property to the new value